# Show markers depending on zoom level?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I have an app where I show a lot of markers

My question is: can I choose a group of markers shows in diferent zoom level?

That is, more zoom in, more marks. Because Showing all markers in map with 13 o 14 zoom is confuse to read.

Comment: yes absolutely; be sure to check this article on google https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers (I assume you use Google Maps)

Comment: th, it same for android?

Comment: yes; the technique described in this article is basically the same for every platform